# How to edit a serialized hash column in form textarea

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization

I have a serialized column in Company model:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :names
```

Ideally I want it to store different names like this in the database:

```
---
short: bestbuy
long: bestbuy ltd.
```

Currently in my company#edit page, I have a text area for it:

```
<%= f.text_area :names %>
```

If I have that YAML in the database, it will be displayed in the browser as:

```
{"short"=>"bestbuy", "long"=>"bestbuy ltd."}
```

However when I submit it, in the database it became:

```
--- ! '{"short"=>"bestbuy", "long"=>"bestbuy ltd."}'
```

***Question***

How can I make it so that textarea displays YAML for editors to edit?

How to make the database save the proper YAML, not a mash of YAML and ruby hash?

***update***

If I force the column to be of type `Hash` like this:

```
serialize :names, Hash
```

it will give error when I try to save:

*ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch in Admin::CompaniesController#update

Attribute was supposed to be a Hash, but was a String*

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A late answer to my own question:

```
class ConfigSerializer
  def self.load(i)
    if i.blank?
      {}
    else
      YAML.load(i)
    end
  end

  def self.dump(i)
    i = {} if i.blank?

    if i.is_a?(String) # Allow assigning an YAML string as input 
      i
    else
      YAML.dump(i)
    end
  end
end
```

and in the model

```
serialize :names, ConfigSerializer
```

This way I can assign a YAML string and it will be stored into the database as is. Only when it is loaded from database it is converted to hash object.

In view I set textarea to have the raw YAML string, so user can edit it.

Answer (score 4):

You can muck about in the database by hand using raw SQL but I wouldn't recommend it if you don't already know what you're doing. A corollary is that you shouldn't be messing around with the database's version of the YAML unless you already know exactly what you're doing.

Instead, convert the data to YAML yourself:

```
@names = m.names.to_yaml
```

and then stuff `@names` into your `<textarea>`. Then to save the edited YAML, parse it back to a Hash and hand it off to your model:

```
m.names = YAML.parse(params[:names])

# Or modify `params` in-place
params[:name] = YAML.load(params[:names])
# then stuff `params` into `m` as usual
```

To be somewhat safe, you should specify that your `names` should be a Hash in the model:

```
serialize :names, Hash
```

I'm not a big fan of [`serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize) so I usually recommend that it not be used; however, if you are going to use it, you should always specify the `class_name` to make it safer to use.

---

Your current approach is putting the `to_s` version of your Hash into the `<textarea>`:

```
{"short"=>"bestbuy", "long"=>"bestbuy ltd."}
```

That's a string, not a Hash; it may look like a Hash but HTML doesn't know what a Ruby Hash is so it is just a string. Then you read that back in and put it into `names` which then YAMLifies (as a string) to this:

```
--- ! '{"short"=>"bestbuy", "long"=>"bestbuy ltd."}'
```

That's a string in YAML, a string that looks a lot like a Hash but a string nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks. I think it should be `YAML.load` instead of `YAML.parse`. I had to do the following in update action: `@company.names = YAML.load(params[:company][:names]); params[:company].delete(:names)`. It's kind of a hassle, the work needed seems to outweigh the convenience. Am am missing something here?

Comment: @lulalala: You're right about `YAML.load`, that was my fingers not doing what my brain told them to. Yes, this is a big hassle but you're trying to subvert `serialize` so that shouldn't be surprising. Why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to make dynamic form fields for each name in the names. However it is difficult as the name types can't be pre-determined. At the end I thought having a textarea for them to edit is probably the easiest to do.

Answer (score -2):

Try to store the names into db like :

```
names = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new({"short"=>"bestbuy", "long"=>"bestbuy ltd."})
company = Company.new
company.names = names.to_yaml
```

hope, it will help .

Comment: This won't work, you'll just end up with YAMLed YAML and that won't help anyone.