# ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: attribute was supposed to be a Hash, but was a String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, hash, ruby-on-rails-2

To get a hash I have this:

```
serialize :colors, Hash
```

But I have an error where it the result of this attribute looks like this:

*To show this I took out the "Hash" from "serialize :colors, Hash" to see the error in the console.*

```
"--- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess \none: \"#87466d\"\ntwo: \"#307065\"\nthree: \"#c04992\"\nfour: \"#ffffff\"\nfive: \"#636467\"\n"
```

Not sure what's happened but seems like the Hash has become a string and I don't' know why. I didn't used to have this problem but I now have two versions of this project where the first is in rails 2 and the other is in rails 3 and I switch between the two. I feel like the error has occurred since going to rails 3 and coming back into rails 2. Anyone know how I can fix this error and why it has occurred?

I looked at a similar post and it hasn't helped me:
["Attribute was supposed to be a Hash, but was a String"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638979/attribute-was-supposed-to-be-a-hash-but-was-a-string)

Answer (score -2):

OK so I fixed it by going into the database and setting the attribute to NULL so that it clears it. As I use MySQL I did the following:

- Open Mysql

  mysql -u root -D database_name -p
- Updated the attribute in Mysql to reset the value:

  UPDATE colors_table SET colors = null WHERE id = 1;

Then I was able to update the values in the rails console without errors.